# need to get reference to the input data in velocity template

Tags: velocity

We have external data which comes in the following format

```
{
                "CountryCode": "AD",
                "CountryName": "Andorra",
                "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
                "Population": "84000",
                "Capital": "Andorra la Vella",
                "ContinentName": "Europe"
}
```

This is passed to the velocity template. We need to get all the keys present in this object and use them ahead . We can use the keyset() function, but the issue which we are facing is we do not have any name for the input data, so we do not know what to write `$<variablename>.keySet()` ?
We tried
`$.keySet()`
`${}.keySet()`
but none worked. Is it possible in velocity to get reference to such an unnamed dataset ?